# Is there any other way to google sign in without google smtp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, gmail, smtplib

I have a flask application which will send emails to the users who will register with their email. I have written the following code and switched on to access less secure app in gmail account.

```py
import smtplib
def send_email():
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.login('Sender's mail id', 'Sender's mail password')
    message = 'sending this from python!'
    server.sendmail('Sender's mail id', 'Receiver's mail id', message)
    server.quit()

send_email()
```

The following error I am getting for this when `send_email()` is being called.

> smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password
>   not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8 
>   https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials z10sm10066531pfa.184
>   - gsmtp')

I later discovered that though I've switched on to access less secure app it remains switched off internally and after some moment on reloading the settings it's shows switched off.

Please help me out I am stuck with my project.

Comment: you could try going though the gmail api or enabling oauth though imap https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol

Comment: Google will automatically turn this setting OFF if it’s not being used

Comment: @DaImTo can you please explain me ?

Comment: @SubhrajyotiDas how it is not being used ? When I am running my script the ```smtplib``` is calling the ```login``` method so i guess it is trying to access the feature ?

Comment: @Avi the less secure apps setting stays off even though you try turning it on?

Comment: maybe generate password for this application and then you don't need access for less secure app.

Comment: @SubhrajyotiDas yes it's showing active in front but it's not active in real & after something it automatically getting turned off